# SAS - SDTM mapping. How to transpose over 20 analytes from H position to V?

Tags: sas, macros, mapping

I have a several datasets that need to be merged together into one domain collecting labs.
STUDYID COUNTRY SITE SUBJID LBTST_lab1 LBTST_lab2 LBTST_lab3 and so on then LBRES_lab1 LBRES_lab2 LBRES_lab3 and so on and more variables.

I need to transpose them as follow:

STUDYID COUNTRY SITE SUBJID LBTEST LBORRES and so on...

| LBTEST | LBORRES | ....... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| lab1 | res1 |  |
| lab2 | res2 |  |

Any suggestions? Thanks

| LBTEST | LBORRES | ....... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| lab1 | res1 |  |
| lab2 | res2 |  |

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: This has been answered in several prior questions.  Search for [sas] array based transpose.   Create a new question if you are having problems merging your data sets.

Comment: The two tables in your question are the same.  Did you mean to show the table you HAVE, and then show the transposed table you WANT?